# Tastypie: How can I fill the resource without database?

Tags: python, django, foursquare, tastypie

I want to grab some information from Foursquare , add some fields and return it via django-tastypie. 
UPDATE:

```
def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):
    near = ''
    if 'near' in request.GET and request.GET['near']:
        near = request.GET['near']
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']

    client = foursquare.Foursquare(client_id=settings.FSQ_CLIENT_ID, client_secret=settings.FSQ_CLIENT_SECRET)

    a = client.venues.search(params={'query': q, 'near' : near, 'categoryId' : '4d4b7105d754a06374d81259' })

    objects = []

    for venue in a['venues']:
        bundle = self.build_bundle(obj=venue, request=request)
        bundle = self.full_dehydrate(bundle)
        objects.append(bundle)

    return objects
```

Now I am getting:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "limit": 20,
    "next": "/api/v1/venue/?q=Borek&near=Kadikoy",
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 30
  },
  "objects": [
    {
      "resource_uri": ""
    },
    {
      "resource_uri": ""
    }]
}
```

There are 2 empty objects. What should I do in order to fill this resource?

Comment: Just do not use ModelResource, as you do nit have model behind it.

Comment: What should I use with Tastypie?

Comment: See my response, I have expanded my comment there.

Comment: Btw. Also it looks like you have NameError exception in your code (not all the variables you use at the end of the function are defined before), unless this is not the whole code you are using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ModelResource` is only suitable when you have ORM Model behind the resource. In other cases you should use `Resource`.

This subject is discussed in `ModelResource` description, mentioning when it is suitable and when it is not: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#why-resource-vs-modelresource

Also there is a whole chapter in the documentation, aimed at providing the details on how to implement non-ORM data sources (in this case: external API): http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html